# Can not find element in postlink of directive creation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, raphael, graphael, justgage

I am trying to create a directive for [JustGauge](http://www.justgage.com) in AngularJS. My html view is something like this:

```
        <div id="guageContainer" class="row" ng-controller="guageCtrl">
            <gauge ng-repeat="ind in indicators" model="ind"></gauge>
        </div>
```

and my directive is:

```
angular.module("pgHome", [])
.directive("gauge", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: { model: "=model" },
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            tElement.append('<div id="{{model.Name}}"></div>');
            return {
                post: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    console.log(scope.model.Name);
                    console.log($("#" + scope.model.Name).length);
                    var g = new JustGage({
                        id: scope.model.Name,
                        value: 348,
                        min: 120,
                        max: 400,
                        title: "test",
                        label: ""
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

When I load the page containing this directive, JustGauge raises an error saying that it can't find an element with corresponding id. Just to mention that the first console.log works well but the second console.log returns 0. Also I am new to angularjs and I couldn't solve this problem!

Comment: Are you including jQuery before Angular?

Comment: @MarkRajcok Yes, I think it must throw an error if it was related to JQuery. By the way, Justgauge does not need jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your JustGage() call in a `$timeout`:

```
.directive("gauge", function ($compile, $timeout) {
   ...
   $timeout(function() {
     var g = new JustGage({...});
   });
```

This gives the browser a chance to render the additional HTML you added in the compile function.  Then the plugin can find the newly added `div`.