# JavaScript code doesn't work on dynamically generated html code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run a JavaScript code after Angular template generated, but I find the JavaScript codes don't run on dynamic generated views.
For example, in this code `div2` is generated by clicking on `div1` and `alert("aaa")` runs by clicking on `div1`, but does not run when `div2` is clicked.

body of index.html

```
<div id="div1" ng-init="showDiv2 = false">
    <div class="alertonclick" ng-click="showDiv2 =true" style="background-color: red"><br/></div>

</div>

<div id="div2" ng-if="showDiv2">
    <div class="alertonclick" style="background-color: green"><br/></div>
</div>
```

and script in index.html:

```
<script src="~/index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".alertonclick").click(function () {
        alert("aaaa");
    });
});
```

Comment: It won't work - as when the page is loaded that div does not exist - so the loaded js won't find that div

Comment: what should i do ? @Haris

Comment: you need to call **$(".alertonclick").click(function () {
        alert("aaaa");
    });** after you html is render

Comment: its an example .i can not generate angular template before html is render @AlpeshJikadra

Comment: I am not telling that you have to call it before html content, You should call it after your angular template render, if possible then create fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: mixing jQuery and Angular is not a good thing, you should learn how to do it the [angular way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: i am trying to use an jquary library in angular app and there is no angular madule for my perpose @Endless

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the association between class `alertonclick` and it's function is done when the page is loaded. But the `div2` isn't created at that point. To fix this, one solution would be to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`:

```
<div id="div1" ng-init="showDiv2 = false">
    <div class="alertonclick" ng-click="showDiv2 =true" style="background-color: red"><br/></div>
</div>

<div id="div2" ng-show="showDiv2">
    <div class="alertonclick" style="background-color: green"><br/></div>
</div>
```

That way the `div2` is generated from the beginning and has the `alertonclick` function but it's hidden.

Comment: what a bout angular templates . templates generate dynamically and not have ng-if or ng-show . is there a way to run index.js codes in angular templates ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896193/angularjs-directive-with-ng-if-in-the-template

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put the click listener for the ".alertonclick" class, after the page was rendered. At that time the second div is not present in the DOM. A possible solution would be to reset the click listener after the second div is displayed.

Comment: i am trying to run js code on angular templates . is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just make sure that the element is present in the DOM before putting the listener for it.